# javascript click button if inactive for 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, button, click, mouse

I've searched for a long long time and made different files which were not working properly.

What i need:
If i'm not interacting with a webpage for 1 minute execute the following:
- click on button.
- repeat click after 30 seconds if i'm still not interacting

When i come back at the webpage (interacting again), i don't want this script to keep running... Only when i'm not interacting again.

I've come to this:

```
function findButtonbyTextContent(text) {
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
if (buttons[i].firstChild.nodeValue == text)
  return buttons[i];
}
}

function refresh(tijd){
setInterval(findButtonbyTextContent("Refresh").click(), tijd);
}

document.onmousemove = (function() {
var onmousestop = function() {
        refresh(30000);
    }, thread;

return function() {
    clearTimeout(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 60000);
};
})();
```

Comment: And what's supposed to happen when you click this button? You can trigger javascript functions, but are you really trying to trigger some native event etc. If so, that would be different?

Comment: This refresh buttons reloads an iframe. The reason i'm not using an id or name of the button is that the webapp changes these values.

I managed to get it working with your other answer. This was great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it

```
var int, timer, btn = document.getElementById('button');

document.onmousemove = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    clearInterval(int);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        int = setInterval(function() {
            btn.click();
        }, 30000);
    }, 60000);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/552swmfn/)

I gave the button an ID and shortened the times in the Fiddle so as to not have to wait for minutes to see the result.

As a sidenote, you're code has some issues, for instance this

```
setInterval(findButtonbyTextContent("Refresh").click(), tijd);
```

calls the click function right away and returns `undefined`, so it doesn't do at all what you think it does, and you're not storing a reference to the interval anywhere, only to the initial setTimeout, and clearing that doesn't clear the interval, it still keeps on going.

Comment: This works great! Instead of btn.click, i used the function findButtonbyTextContent("Refresh").click()